# is rocketmq transactional message 2PC or 3PC?

Tags: transactions, rocketmq

I tend to believe 3PC ,but offical document says 2PC .
offical document link: https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/featureBehavior/04transactionmessage/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2i7K.png)

the reason why is think it is 3PC is the step to write msg to half msg queue. I think this step is eqaual to pre-commit in 3PC.

Comment: Is there a practical programming problem arising from this? If not, then your question is off-topic. You might do better asking on the RocketMQ community pages.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2pc.

Because it's core step is:

1. send a half message to Broker.
2. when you commit the transaction than broker will transfer the half message to normal topic.